# set the width of select2 input (through Angular-ui directive)

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs, jquery-select2

I have problem making this plunkr (select2 + angulat-ui) work.

http://plnkr.co/edit/NkdWUO?p=preview

In local setup, I get the select2 work, but I cannot set the width as described in the [docs](http://angular-ui.github.com/#directives-select2). It is too narrow to be used.

[image]

Thank you.

EDIT:
Never mind that plnkr, I found a working fiddle here
http://jsfiddle.net/pEFy6/

It looks like it is the behavior of select2 to collapse to the width of first element. I could set the width through bootstrap `class="input-medium"` .Still not sure why angular-ui doesn't take config parameters.

Comment: Can you be more specific as far as what you've tried already? The chosen library (on which select2 is based) will generate a width based on the width provided in the HTML/CSS.

Answer (score 230, accepted):

You need to specify the attribute width to resolve in order to preserve element width

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#myselect").select2({ width: 'resolve' });           
});
```

Comment: $("#myselect").select2({ placeholder: 'Select Country', width: '192px' }); solved my problem with IE and have no effect on FF and Chrome! Thanks!

Comment: yes. I also asked author
https://github.com/godbasin/vue-select2/issues/11

Answer (score 285):

In my case the select2 would open correctly if there was zero or more pills.

But if there was one or more pills, and I deleted them all, it would shrink to the smallest width.  My solution was simply:

```
$("#myselect").select2({ width: '100%' });
```

Comment: best answer if using select2 version 4.0.0

Comment: why this is better than $("#myselect").select2({ width: 'resolve' }); ? (seems to be the same)

Comment: @RicardoVigatti:
width:'resolve' does only work once on load of the page but not on resize.
If your'e using responsive designs it doesnt do the trick

Comment: `resolve` didn't work for me - 100%` did. that's half an hour hopelessly searching for an answer "resolved". thanks :)

Comment: This is the best answer so far. But now, for me, the search field doesn't fill all the width. Any easy way to correct this?

Answer (score 56):

This is an old question but new info is still worth posting...

Starting with Select2 version 3.4.0 there is an attribute `dropdownAutoWidth` which solves the problem and handles all the odd cases. Note it is not on by default. It resizes dynamically as the user makes selections, it adds width for `allowClear` if that attribute is used, and it handles placeholder text properly too.

```js
$("#some_select_id").select2({
    dropdownAutoWidth : true
});
```

Comment: It works pretty well... except if you are using placeholders, if you are, if your options are smaller than the placeholder, the placeholder text will be truncated :(

Answer (score 25):

select2 V4.0.3

```
<select class="smartsearch" name="search" id="search" style="width:100%;"></select>
```

Answer (score 15):

With > 4.0 of select2 I am using

```
$("select").select2({
  dropdownAutoWidth: true
});
```

These others did not work:

- dropdownCssClass: 'bigdrop'
- width: '100%'
- width: 'resolve'

Answer (score 10):

add method container css in your script like this :

```
$("#your_select_id").select2({
      containerCss : {"display":"block"}
});
```

it will set your select's width same as width your div.

Comment: This did the trick for me (I couldn't get select2 to automatically resize with Bootstrap 3). Although I have to say it's a bit hacky.

Comment: This set me on the right track, I replaced display with minWidth: `$( '.opt-option-type-select' ).select2( {
   containerCss : {
    minWidth: '10em',
   },
  } );`

Answer (score 7):

Add width resolve option to your select2 function

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#myselect").select2({ width: 'resolve' });           
});
```

After add below CSS to your stylesheet

```
.select2-container {
width: 100% !important;
}
```

It will sort the issue

Answer (score 2):

Setting width to 'resolve' didn't work for me. 
Instead, i added "width:100%" to my select, and modified the css like this :

`.select2-offscreen {position: fixed !important;}`

This was the only solution that worked for me (my version is 2.2.1)
Your select will take all the available place, it is better than using

`class="input-medium"`

from bootstrap, because the select is always staying in the container, even after resizing the window (responsive)

Comment: Thanks for the solution but it only worked for me on first load. Once I selected a tag and then clicked on another page element the select2 input went back to the incorrect size

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to add my solution here as well. This is similar to Ravindu's answer above.

I added `width: 'resolve',` as a property within the select2:

```
    $('#searchFilter').select2({
        width: 'resolve',
    });
```

Then I added a `min-width` property to `select2-container` with `!important`:

```
.select2-container {
    min-width: 100% !important;
}
```

On the select element, the `style='100px !important;'` attribute needed `!important` to work:

```
<select class="form-control" style="width: 160px;" id="searchFilter" name="searchfilter[]">
```

Answer (score 2):

Add this in your stylesheet:

```css
.select2 {
  width: unset !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Other Way you can use is setting width in style on your Select tag.

```
<select id="myselect" style="width: 20%;">
    <option>...</option>
</select>
```

Then, use this

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $("#myselect").select2({ width: 'style' }); //This will use style attr of the select element  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try like this. It works for me

`$("#MISSION_ID").select2();`

On hide/show or ajax request, we have to reinitialize the select2 plugin

For example:

```
$("#offialNumberArea").show();
$("#eventNameArea").hide();

$('.selectCriteria').change(function(){
    var thisVal = $(this).val();
    if(thisVal == 'sailor'){
        $("#offialNumberArea").show();
        $("#eventNameArea").hide();
    }
    else
    {
        $("#offialNumberArea").hide();
        $("#eventNameArea").show();
        $("#MISSION_ID").select2();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Easier CSS solution independent from select2

```
//HTML
<select id="" class="input-xlg">
</select>
<input type="text" id="" name="" value="" class="input-lg" />

//CSS
.input-xxsm {
  width: 40px!important; //for 2 digits 
}

.input-xsm {
  width: 60px!important; //for 4 digits 
}

.input-sm {
  width: 100px!important; //for short options   
}

.input-md {
  width: 160px!important; //for medium long options 
}

.input-lg {
  width: 220px!important; //for long options    
}

.input-xlg {
  width: 300px!important; //for very long options   
}

.input-xxlg {
  width: 100%!important; //100% of parent   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On a recent project built using **Bootstrap 4**, I had tried all of the above methods but nothing worked. My approach was by editing the **library** **CSS** using **jQuery** to get **100%** on the table.

```
 // * Select2 4.0.7

$('.select2-multiple').select2({
    // theme: 'bootstrap4', //Doesn't work
    // width:'100%', //Doesn't work
    width: 'resolve'
});

//The Fix
$('.select2-w-100').parent().find('span')
    .removeClass('select2-container')
    .css("width", "100%")
    .css("flex-grow", "1")
    .css("box-sizing", "border-box")
    .css("display", "inline-block")
    .css("margin", "0")
    .css("position", "relative")
    .css("vertical-align", "middle")
```

Working **Demo**

```js
$('.select2-multiple').select2({
        // theme: 'bootstrap4', //Doesn't work
        // width:'100%',//Doens't work
        width: 'resolve'
    });
    //Fix the above style width:100%
    $('.select2-w-100').parent().find('span')
        .removeClass('select2-container')
        .css("width", "100%")
        .css("flex-grow", "1")
        .css("box-sizing", "border-box")
        .css("display", "inline-block")
        .css("margin", "0")
        .css("position", "relative")
        .css("vertical-align", "middle")
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/css/select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
        <tr>
            <th scope="col" class="w-50">#</th>
            <th scope="col" class="w-50">Trade Zones</th>
        </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>
                1
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control select2-multiple select2-w-100" name="sellingFees[]"
                        multiple="multiple">
                    <option value="1">One</option>
                    <option value="1">Two</option>
                    <option value="1">Three</option>
                    <option value="1">Okay</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.7/js/select2.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is work for me. After create select componant and then add your customer css attribute.

```
$(select).select2({
//....create select componant content
});

$("span.select2-container").addClass(yourDefClass);
```

In the css file. configure your style and add !important.

```
.yourDefClass{
    width: 700px !important;
}
```