# select2 not display correct select field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, jquery-select2

I have a form search like this:

[image: filter]

When i used [select2](https://ivaynberg.github.io/select2/) for `select#search_topic`, this become:

[image: filter_error]

This is my select2 code:

```
<% content_for :head do %>
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#search_topic').select2();
});
  </script>
<% end %>
```

My form:

```
<%= form_tag({ controller: 'questions', action: 'search_filter' }, method: 'get', class: 'form-inline') do %>
  <%= label_tag 'search_topic', 'Filter:', class: 'label_search' %> 
  <%= select_tag 'search_topic', options_from_collection_for_select(current_user.get_topics, :id, :name), :prompt => "Select topic" %>
  <%= select_tag 'search_type', options_from_collection_for_select(@question_types, :id, :name), :prompt => "Select type question" %>
  <%= submit_tag "Search", name: nil, class: 'btn' %>
<% end %>
```

I have copied `select2.js` and `select2.css.scss`(change name from selec2.css) to `vendor/javascript` and `vendor/stylesheet`.

And I changed `url('select2.png')` in scss file to `image_url("select2.png")`. I also copied `select2.png` to `app/assets/images`.

In `application.js` i have `//= require select2`. In `application.css.scss` i have `@import "select2";`.
What is wrong with my code?

Comment: You should use a plain text input instead of `select_tag` - `hidden_field_tag`. See the official docs for examples.

Comment: @antonk what do you mean plain text?

Comment: I mean, select2 requires <input>, not <select>

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to set a default width for the select.

http://ivaynberg.github.com/select2/index.html

search page for width

also if you add :multiple => "" it uses the multiple text box version

Comment: It didn't work, I did it before. But I found the answer in [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12683907/set-the-width-of-select2-input-through-angular-ui-directive) + set the first item for dropdown list.